# Cloud function http function fails on first run

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am testing with a payment processing system and every time a transaction is completed, the payment processor should hit my endpoint with a POST request with payment details so I can save it to my database (Firestore).

Only thing is the function fails on the first try. What I mean is, say a customer pays, the payment processor hits my cloud function, it fails to save to my database. When a second customer makes the transaction a minute, 5 minutes or even 18 minutes later according to my observation, everything works as expected.

Am I facing a cold start problem or what is happening. And how do I solve this.

Here is my function

```js
exports.stkCallback = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    if (request.method === 'POST') {
        
       if (request.body.Body.stkCallback.ResultCode === 0) {   
            const jsonData = request.body.Body.CallbackMetadata;
            console.log("USER HAS COMPLETED THE TRANSACTION");

            var transactionID;
            
            ///This below line logs successfully everytime meaning my payment processor has sent the POST 
            /// request
            console.log("checkoutid:", request.body.Body.CheckoutRequestID)


            ///I have saved the CheckoutRequestID previously to Firestore so I first query the document 
            //// with that ID (CheckoutRequestID) and get its data so I can update the transaction as 
             //// complete

            var docRef=db.collection("Transactions").doc(request.body.Body.CheckoutRequestID);

await docRef.get().then((doc) =>{
    // eslint-disable-next-line promise/always-return
    if (doc.exists) {
        //console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        transactionID=doc.id;
        transactionData.push(doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch((error)=> {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});


///Once I get the data I can then go ahead and do other operations. 
///Only the above query fails the first time which I don't know why
///By failing Saying No such Document. Which the document does exist


***carrying out other operations using the fetched transactionID and transactionData***




          response.sendStatus(200);

            
        } else {
            console.log("USER HAS CANCELLED THE TRANSACTION");
            response.sendStatus(200);
        }
```

I have refactored my code and reproduced it to the below

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.stkCallback = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    const accountSid = "#";
const authToken = "#";
const client = require("twilio")(accountSid, authToken);
    if (request.method === 'POST') {

        
       if (request.body.Body.ResultCode === 0) {   
            const jsonData = request.body.Body.CallbackMetadata;
            console.log("USER HAS COMPLETED THE TRANSACTION");

            var transactionID;

///This below line logs successfully everytime meaning my 
/////payment processor has sent the POST request
            console.log("checkoutid:", 
                   request.body.Body.CheckoutRequestID)
            
////The below function is critical to all the other below functions below it as
 ///it supplies the necessary data all the way down
///It is also the function that fails on the first run

            var docRef= await db.collection("Transactions").doc(request.body.Body.CheckoutRequestID).get()
                .catch((error)=> {
                    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
                });

//// a log of some data from the above function
//// when it fails, the below log is undefined,
           console.log("tyyy",docRef.data().Home)
           transactionID=docRef.id;


////the data returned from above function is used to perform other operations.
////Below is just one of them
////consequently, it will fail as some values like doc.data().Uid will be ////undefined


await db.collection("Users").doc(doc.data().Uid).collection("Transactions").doc(transactionID).update({
    TransactionComplete: true,
    transactionCompletedTimeDb: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    Amount: jsonData.Item[0].Value,
    ReceiptNO: jsonData.Item[1].Value,
    TransactionDate: jsonData.Item[3].Value,
    PhoneNumber: jsonData.Item[4].Value,
    UserId: doc.data().Uid
    })
    // eslint-disable-next-line promise/always-return
    
    .catch((error)=> {
    // The document probably doesn't exist.
    console.error("Error updating document: ", error); 
    });


          response.sendStatus(200);


        } else {
            console.log("USER HAS CANCELLED THE TRANSACTION");
            response.sendStatus(200);
        }

});
```

Attaching an image of a failed function, do note the time
[image: Failed function]

An image of logs of the same triggered function right after (3 minutes later). As you can see the function completes successfully

[image: Successful function]

Comment: please, provide a stacktrace

Comment: What happens if you use `response.send()` or `response.end()` instead of `response.sendStatus()`? See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#trigger_a_function_with_an_http_request

Comment: Too much of your function is redacted.  You are likely doing something wrong with promises where it says "carrying out other operations using the fetched transactionID and transactionData".  You must only send a response after all promises are complete.  Also you shouldn't mix `await` with `then` - that is generally a bad practice. Please edit the question to show the complete minimal code the reproduces the issue.

Comment: Everyone who voted a close to my question Kindly revisit it. I have added all the necessary logs needed

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a Cold Start Issue

The mitigation of this issue will depend on many information that you are not sharing with us like the complete function, dependencies that you are using, and instance size.

Spreading a loaded function into multiple small functions will help with the cold start time, also using smaller, updated, and cloud oriented libraries will also help.

Also, the size of the payload could be an important factor here, how big is the size of the payload sent to the function and how big is the size of the info that you are writing into the logs? All these small pieces have an important influence on the performance of a cold start.

As a quick solution for your Issue, I can safely say that creating a Scheduled task that triggers your functions every 30 minutes, for example, would be enough to mitigate your issue in the short term.

Comment: Cold starts don't cause a delay of "a minute, 5 minutes or even 18 minutes later".  They are, at most, a few seconds.

Comment: There is not a delay 5 or 18 minutes later, is clearly stated that further request made to the function "works as expected", so if only first start on a while fails cold start is on the list of things to troubleshoot

Comment: @DougStevenson as Chris32 has stated. The first (transaction)/customer is always the one that suffers the error. During a window of maximum probably 18 minutes after first trigger is when everything works. Say after another 30 minutes, an error occurs again